# Check if integer is in objects attribute array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have the following structure:

```
$foo_array = array(
  [0] => object(foo) {
    'id' => 1
  }
  [1] => object(foo) {
    'id' => 2
  }
)
```

And I want to check, if int(1) exists in this array's id attribute. How can I do that?

I've been thinking about something like `in_array(1, $foo_array)`, but of course it doesn't work.

Comment: try this:- `foreach($foo_array as $foo){if($foo->id == 1){echo "yes";}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just use  [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php), e.g.

```
array_reduce($arr, function($keep, $v){
    if($v->id == 1)
        return $keep = TRUE;
    return $keep;
}, FALSE);
```

Comment: @KarolHernik Forgot to copy something. updated it now and it should work

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `array_column` as (PHP >= 5.5)

```
in_array(1, array_column($foo_array,'id'))
```